# In R, how can I read a .txt file and all the individual values in the .txt file separately?

Tags: r, read.table

I am currently trying to read a `.txt` file in `R` and the file contains 561 different values per row. The 561 different values are all separated from each other by a space and the different rows containing the 561 values are all separated by a tab. So I was wondering, how can I go about to read in all the rows of the `.txt` file while also reading in all the different values in each row individually?

My code currently is

```
read.table("X_test_copy.txt", sep = "\t")
```

The problem with those code is that it reads all the 561 different values per row as one individual value in `R`, instead of different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 lines <- scan(file="path/to/file/file.ext", what="", sep="\t")  # input as character
 my.df <- read.table(text=lines)
```

Comment: What is the 'what' parameter mean? I have looked it up but I cannot quite understand what it is doing in this code

Comment: It's determining what mode to use, "character" in this case. If you were entering number it have been `what =numeric()`. The `""` just gives an "example" of "what" is being entered.